# Finding the optimum value of a variable subject to a nonlinear constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

[image]

I want to know whether or not the objective function I have defined is correct. The nonlinear constraint has to be satisfied while ζ varies from 0 < ζ <= 1/2.

This is the first time I am trying to do optimization with Mathematica. It would be helpful if you would direct me to any documentation that can help me.

```
ClearAll 
f[β_] := β;
(*Objective function*)
a = 1/(2*β^3); 
eq = 
  a*(((Sin[β*(1 - ζ)]*Sin[β*ζ])/Sin[β]) - ((Sinh[β*(1 - ζ)]*Sinh[β*ζ])/Sinh[β])); 
eq1 = (10^12*eq) + 1;
(*This is the constraint equation*)
NMaximize[f[β_], eq1 == 0]
```

Comment: Have a look at [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html?q=NMaximize).

Comment: ClearAll
f[\[Beta]_] := \[Beta];(*Objective function *)
a = 1/(2*\[Beta]^3);
eq = a*(((Sin[\[Beta]*(1 - \[Zeta])]*Sin[\[Beta]*\[Zeta]])/
      Sin[\[Beta]]) - ((
      Sinh[\[Beta]*(1 - \[Zeta])]*Sinh[\[Beta]*\[Zeta]])/
      Sinh[\[Beta]]));
eq1 = (10^12*eq) + 1;(*This is the constraint equation*)
NMaximize[f[\[Beta]_], eq1 == 0]

Comment: But how to define variation of zeta from 0 <zeta<=0.5

Comment: If you add copyable code to your question, rather than an image of an equation, more people might be willing to help out.

Comment: 1) `ClearAll` is not a Mathematica command and therefore is ignored. 2) Why does your code have a factor of 10^12 that does not appear in the image you originally posted?

Comment: It is a typo, i forget to put in latex. sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
f[β_] = β; (*Objective function*)
a = 1/(2*β^3);
eq = a*(((Sin[β*(1 - ζ)]*Sin[β*ζ])/Sin[β]) - ((Sinh[β*(1 - ζ)]*Sinh[β*ζ])/Sinh[β]));
eq1 = (10^12*eq) + 1; (*This is the constraint equation*)
```

Use the proper syntax as shown in the documentation for [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html): "NMaximize[{f, cons}, {x, y,…}] maximizes `f` numerically subject to the constraints `cons`."

```
NMaximize[{f[β], eq1 == 0, 0 < ζ <= 1/2}, {β, ζ}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50] // N

(* {3.92685, {β -> 3.92685, ζ -> 0.00015584}} *)
```

**EDIT:** "For nonlinear functions, `NMaximize` may sometimes find only a local maximum."

```
NMaximize[{f[β], eq1 == 0, 
   0 < ζ <= 1/2}, {{β, 3, 10}, ζ}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] //
  N

(* {7.07025, {β -> 7.07025, ζ -> 0.000364042}} *)
```